# Fandol with LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, fontspec, cjk, luaotfload

The next release of `babel` will provide basic line breaking for CJK with `luatex`. When I was making some experiments I discovered an odd and puzzling behaviour in the Fandol family. The file is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FandolSong-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}

\section{现代建筑教育}

中国的现代建筑教育体系不是来自本土建筑营造的延续

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: Error with FandolSong and LuaTeX]

Note the section body follows the title without any vertical break. It works as expected with `xetex` and with many other fonts in `luatex`, but not with Fandol. (TeXLive 2018 and 2019.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is going on here? Let's start by looking at what `\section` actually does: In `article.cls`, `\section` is defined by

```
    \newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

In `source2e.pdf`, we can find an explenation of all the parameters of `\@startsection`. For the fifth, it says

> **afterskip:** if positive, then skip to leave below heading, else negative of skip to
>   leave to right of run-in heading.

What you observe with Fandol is a run-in heading with no space between heading and regular text, so obviously the second case is triggered. But this means that the parameter is *not positive*. This might appear odd, because the command above passes `{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}`, which certainly looks positive.

But let's take a step back and look what `{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}` actually is: The `\@plus...}` is not relevant for us, so we just look at `2.3ex`. Here the unit `ex` is the "x-height" of the current font, but a `x-height` is not meaningful for a CJK-font like Fandol. Now in the corresponding OpenType field, Fandol has to set some value, so Fandol sets its "x-height" to `0`.
This is picked up by luaotfload, which passes the x-height `0` to LuaTeX. Now `2.3ex=2.3*"x-height"=2.3*0=0`.

So the `afterskip` parameter is set to `0`, which is not positive.
So in conformance with it's documentation, `\@startsection` produces a run-in heading, leaving no space to right of run-in heading.

Now the difference between XeTeX and luaotfload is the handling of missing x-height values:

luaotfload only uses a fallback if the font does not contain any x-height, while XeTeX also uses the fallback if the font explicitly specifies a x-height of `0`.
You can emulate the XeTeX behaviour in LuaTeX by patching the font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\directlua{
  luatexbase.add_to_callback("luaotfload.patch_font", function (fontdata)
    local parameters = fontdata.parameters
    if not parameters then return end
    if not (parameters.x_height or parameters[5] or 0) == 0 then return end
    if fontdata.characters and fontdata.characters[120] then
      parameters.x_height = fontdata.characters[120].height
    else
      parameters.x_height = (parameters.ascender or 0)/2
    end
  end, "Fix x-height")
}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FandolSong-Regular.otf}

\begin{document}
\section{现代建筑教育}

中国的现代建筑教育体系不是来自本土建筑营造的延续

\end{document}
```

This ensures that the x-height is (almost) never zero, so `\section` works again:
[image]

Comment: Ah you found the zero ex value too. I wonder we should add the patch generally. In latex ex is used quite often, so it is probably better if it is (almost) never 0.

Comment: This can sometimes happen with non-CJK fonts. For example, I encountered it with Quattrocento, loaded via the `quattrocento` package. It does seem wise to exactly replicate pdflatex's behaviour here, since the effects of having an ex-height of zero can be quite perplexing. Actually I've no idea how I even found that this StackExchange answer was relevant; it was a stab in the dark! But the above Lua code does fix it. BTW this also happens for Quattrocento in XeLaTeX (where I obviously can't use the Lua workaround).

Comment: @DairaHopwood I don't know what you mean by "replicate pdflatex's behaviour", but at least the Lua code above will most likely be applied by default after the next luaotfload release.

Comment: Quattrocento is not a CJK font. But it has essentially the same issue with ex height being detected as zero, when loaded via the `quattrocento` package. (For all I know it's just a bug in that package.)

Comment: @DairaHopwood Oh, now I see what you meant. But at least on my system (up-to-date TeXLive 2019) I am unable to reproduce. Quattrocento has a non-zero "x-height", even if it is much smaller than the actual x-height of the font.